# Is there a difference between doing $(foo) and `foo`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have noticed that both are used in similar contexts, like:

```
MONTH=`date +%m`
DAY=$(date +%d)
```

So, I wonder:

- Is there a difference between the two, or you can use them interchangeably?
- Are both adhered to POSIX?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, you are correct - somehow, I didn't get that question suggested when I was creating this one... odd.  What should I do with this question?  Should I close it?

Comment: Mmmm it is difficult to say, but to me it makes sense to keep this one. At the end, this is another "entry" to that concept, so some people may find this question and then go to that one, where the answers stay.